# How to remove a character in the last element of a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following list :

```
mylist = ["test1","test2","test3\n"]
```

I am trying to remove the `\n` in the last element, here is how i tried :

```
mylist = ["test1","test2","test3\n"]
print(mylist)
> ['test1', 'test2', 'test3\n']

mylist[-1].strip("\n") # trying with .replace("\n", "") don't work too
print(mylist)
> ['test1', 'test2', 'test3\n']
```

I miss why it doesn't work, i can't use strip or replace on an element of a list ? Only a string ?

PS : `mylist[-1]` is the right element, but as you can see, `\n` is interpreted :

```
print(mylist[-1])
> test3
```

Sorry for possible duplicate, i couldn't find my error.

Comment: `strip` doesn't act in-place, it returns the new string. `replace` does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Running `.strip()` (or any `str` method, for that matter, including `.replace()`) doesn't change the original string. Do `mylist[-1] = mylist[-1].strip("\n")`